# Ошибка "конфликт имен"

Tags: c++

У меня проблема при объявлении константы в начале кода. У меня компилятор дает ошибку, не видя её (константу) в main; если объявить в самом классе, тогда не видит функция. Вот, например:

```
using namespace std;

const int max = 5;

int main()
{
    void centimize(double *);
    double varray[max] = { 10.0, 41.1, 95.9, 87.4, 87.3 };
    centimize(varray);

    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
        cout << "varray [ " << j << "] = " << varray[j] <<
            "сантимаетров " << endl;
    return 0;
}

void centimize(double *ptrd)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
        *ptrd++ *= 2.54;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте double varray[max+1] = ...

Comment: А что за ошибка?

Comment: reference to ‘max’ is ambiguous <br />
путается между max и std:max

Comment: Насчет max+1, это конечно моя ошибка. Черт попутал, не запускал, подумал, что м.б. компилятор ругается на несовпадение размера массива и инициализацию. Думаю, что @cy6erGn0m прав.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас какой-то clash. Похоже что max уже где-то в стандартных внутренностях объявлена. Переименуйте max во что-нибудь другое и всё взлетит.

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали `using namespace std;` и теперь поиск имен видит две сущности с именем `max` - `const int max` и шаблон функции `std::max`.

Используйте префикс глобального пространства имен `::` чтобы явно указать, что надо брать имя из глобального пространства имен (а не из пространства имен `::std::`)

```
double varray[::max] = {...};
```

Более правильное решение - это не использовать `using namespace std;`.